# Code doesn't output correctly

Tags: c, recursion, palindrome

I can't find the problem in my code, it prints only press any key to continue nothing else. I don't seem to figure out the flow of the program because of the output shown.
Help appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int fcheck(char *name, int i, int j)
{
    if (i > j)
        return 1;

    if (name[i] != name[j])
        return 0;
    else
        fcheck(name, i++, j--);

    return 1;
}                               // close fcheck

int main()
{
    int c;

    char name[] = "mom";

    int i = 0, j = 2;

    c = fcheck(name, i, j);

    if (c == 1)
        printf("Palindrome");
    else
        printf("Not a Palindrome");

    return 0;
}                               // close main
```

Comment: Isn't something missing here: `fcheck(name, ...);`?

Comment: Run your code in a debugger.  Set a breakpoint, step through the instructions, watch the value of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Infinite loop problem

this line

```
fcheck(name,i++,j--);
```

should be

```
fcheck(name,++i,--j);
```

because

```
fcheck(name,i++,j--);
```

is equivalent to

```
fcheck(name,i,j);
i++;
j--;
```

so with this way of incrementation you will get an infinite loop because you are recalling `fcheck()` with the same arguments

and

fcheck(name,++i,--j);

is equivalent to

```
i++;
j--;
fcheck(name,i,j);
```

with this way you are not recalling `fcheck()` with the same arguments. So it should fix your infinite loop problem

2) should add return after the recursive call

As mentioned in the other answer, you should add return when you call the recursive function

```
return fcheck(name, ++i, --j);
```

Comment: You have a fair point about pre-fix/post-fix.  But you totally *missed* that this should be `return fcheck(name, ++i, --j);`  That ***return*** is extremely important.

Comment: @abelenky You are totally right I missed that in my answer. But BLUEPIXY has mentioned that in his answer

Comment: @abelenky any way in my answer I already mentioned in my answer that this fix the infinite loop problem of the OP question.

Answer (score 2):

```
fcheck(name,i++,j--);
```

only changes the values of `i` or `j` after calling `fcheck`.  This means that you get a repeating callstack for `fcheck(name,0,2)` which only terminates when your stack overflows.

If you want to use recursion here, you need to use pre-increment/decrement instead

```
return fcheck(name,++i,--j);
```

Note that I've also added a `return` here.  Without this, any string whose first and last characters match will be reported a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
int fcheck(char *name, int i, int j){
    if (i > j)
        return 1;

    if (name[i] != name[j])
        return 0;

    return fcheck(name, i+1, j-1);
}
```